# Check if Page.RouteData.Values has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am getting an error when running

```
string quote = Page.RouteData.Values["quote"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

*Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I understand that ToString is causing the error since the Page.RouteData.Values["quote"] is empty/null.

How do I check to see if the **Page.RouteData.Values**["quote"] has a value before we do the ToString?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["quote"] != null) {
    string quote = Page.RouteData.Values["quote"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

or

```
string quote = ((Page.RouteData.Values["quote"] != null) ? Page.RouteData.Values["quote"].ToString() : string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var quote = Page.RouteData.Values["quote"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```